# double precision in Ada?

Tags: double, precision, ada, numeric

I'm very new to Ada and was trying to see if it offers double precision type. I see that we have float and

```
Put( Integer'Image( Float'digits ) );
```

on my machine gives a value of 6, which is not enough for numerical computations.

Does Ada has double and long double types as in C?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: While we are on the subject of real numbers, you may want to look into Ada's Fixed-point support as well.

Comment: Thanks. I've started reading on Ada and I will look into this later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a wee bit more complicated than that.

The only predefined floating-point type that compilers *have to* support is `Float`. Compilers may optionally support `Short_Float` and `Long_Float`. You should be able to look in appendex F of your compiler documentation to see what it supports.

In practice, your compiler almost certianly defines `Float` as a 32-bit IEEE float, and `Long_Float` as a 64-bit. Note that C pretty much works this way too with its `float` and `double`. C doesn't actually define the size of those.

If you absolutely **must** have a certian precision (eg: you are sharing the data with something external that must use IEEE 64-bit), then you should probably define your own float type with exactly that precision. That would ensure your code is either portable to any platform or compiler you move it to, or that it will produce a compiler error so you can fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Long_Float and I got 15 digits :) and I'm very happy with this :). I'm using the AdaGIDE IDE with GNAT compiler.

Comment: Gnat on x86's actually supports a (totally non-portable) Long_Long_Float that uses all 80 digits the Intel FPU's have, if you want to go hog-wild.

Comment: I get 18 digits with Long_Long_Float. This is largely more than enough for numerical calculations.

Answer (score 6):

You can create any size Float you like.  For a long it would be:

```
type My_Long_Float is digits 11;
```

[Wiki Books](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming) is a good reference for things like this.

Comment: I'm very new to Ada. I'm testing my IDE and compiler and see if I can run Ada programs. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This is true. In practice, you might have a bit of trouble using oddball floats that aren't compatible with your FPU (assuming you want hardware floats). However, this is exactly what you want to do if you have an exact size float you want to use, no matter what compiler/platform your code ends up on.